Any alternative to 'function' or 'functionality'?
Any device, tool, machine has a number of tasks they are designed to perform. Only term I have to fit aptly describe their ability to perform a task is 'function'. There is also 'feature' but except for electronic devices that sounds like a characteristic of the machine rather than a capability. So, any terms other than 'function', 'functionality', or 'capability'.
Edit: Example sentence-
He opened the flood gates, letting the high pressure water streams move through the contraption activating it. The inbuilt ---- of the device made the platform rise at constant pace.
Main problem with 'function' and 'feature' is that neither is able to capture the sense of magical wonder(I don't really have a better way to put it) that such a device is supposed to inspire.

I don't understand "except for electronic devices that sounds like a characteristic of the machine rather than a capability". Please give a specific context (an actual sentence, with a blank for the target word) and explain more fully why you don't like 'functionality', or 'capability'.

A machine might have a purpose, use or benefit etc. Picking the best term requires more context. Would you mind [edit]ing your question to include that context? A sample sentence with "xxx" as a placeholder for the word can also help - though not a trivial one like "I'm looking for the word xxx". Something more like "The ___ of the air conditioner is to cool a hot room or warm up a cold room" or "The main ___ of a dishwasher over soap-and-towel is that we don't need to do the heavy scrubbing."

It is unclear what the motivation for this question is. If function is a good word for your purposes, why do you need an alternative one? Why is none of the words that can be found in a thesaurus suitable for your purposes?

I'm not clear on "able to capture the sense of magical wonder that such a device is supposed to inspire." Are you suggesting that every device is supposed to inspire a  sense of magical wonder? I've never been in a design meeting where that was a requirement of the feature set.

"Functionality" or "capabilities" seem to fit in the example sentence. You'll have to explain in more detail what kind of word you want - with the mention of magical wonder do you want something archaic or mystical-sounding or Eastern or just rarer or more incomprehensible?

@StuartF archaic or mystical-sounding.

Did you go through the thesaurus links to see what the nearby alternatives might be? Your desired meaning of 'capturing the sense of magical wonder' is not a common semantic feature of words... you'll probably only get lucky if a single word even hints at that. Consider using more than one word.

OK, after the edit it has become much clearer what you are trying to do, but it seems that this would be most easily accomplished by using some mundane noun (such as feature or capability), qualified by an adjective such as fascinating, ingenious, or awesome. Why do you need a single word for the purpose?

"He opened the flood gates and the high-pressure of the water streams activated the contraption, which caused the platform to rise at a constant pace.*
